# Using Clojure in Repl without opening en closing parentheses

Tags: clojure

I am curious if it is possible to write a function in clojure that can be called from the repl without opening and closing parentheses. I use for example always the following function:

`(defn ll [] (load-file "D:\\work.clj"))`

I have to call this with (ll) but it would come in handy if only ll was needed.

[My idea comes from autocad/autolisp. In there I can define a function like `(defun c:somecommand () . . )`

From this point on I can use somecommand on the commandline (because of 'c:' before the command. Without parentheses.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but you shouldn't ;)

Here's an example that misuses (IMHO) reify to override `.toString` to have a side-effect.

```
(def m (reify Object (toString [this] (println "Evil side effect") "foo")))
#'user/m
user=> m
Evil side effect
#object[user$reify__151 0x3350ebdd "foo"]
```

Comment: granted, no useful return value possible, just side-effects

Comment: Thanks Jochen. I know my way arond in AutoLisp and to some extend in Clojure (both lisps). But I am not a professionel programmer. Therefore I am curious to what you exactly mean. Is it that side-effects should be avoided and that this solution is in fact counter-funtional (as a matter of speeking)?

Comment: It's misusing the `toString` method in the underlying Java object and works by accident as the REPL uses `toString` to print out information about the binding of m. 
(and in general Clojure developers are trying to keep functions with side-effect at the outer boundary of a system and work with pure functions only.
That said, for a little helper tool in your REPL, it's probably ok

Comment: Thanks again Jochen. I now realise that I do not want a function. I want some tool to do something. In this case your m to load a file for me. I want something not-clojure at this level. But it conflicts with the fact, that it is unavoidable Clojure.
I wil soon post another question that lives around the same issue. How to prevent a function from returning anything. Not even nil. Also not a functional idea I guess.

Comment: here's another option: run your own REPL! It's not hard and you can intercept anything and dispatch commands before handing it to the underlying REPL

Comment: Here are a few handy alternatives: https://clojure.org/guides/repl/enhancing_your_repl_workflow

Comment: and here's another article that might help: https://lambdaisland.com/guides/clojure-repls/clojure-repls

Comment: It will take a while to grasp it all. I am not a quick learner. I want to code with Clojure but it appears I can't avoid being busy with the things around it. Learn better REPL, Leiningen, the edtior and integration of all this. I am now busy with Microsoft Visual Code with Calva. Promises a lot but for now my keybord shortcuts don't work well. Happens to a lot of users. Do I have to switch to another tool? Lighttabel for example? Getting tired of this type of problems.
A discussion about your m function and if we should use it or not, is much more important to learn from!
Thanks again.

Comment: no worries, take it slow. There are quite a few choices, which is a boon but also overwhelming and confusing. I've been through this stage only recently myself.
I'm using Intelllij + Cursive plugin with Emacs bindings which works fine and was simple to get going with. Good luck on your Clojure journey. It's a tall order but totally worth it